# Presto showing everything null

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-s3, presto, presto-jdbc

I configured Single node Presto cluster and able to create tables from the data in my custom s3 service. However when I try to query data like `select * from test limit 10;` the result I am getting here is like this -

```
 time | quality |  o3
------+---------+------
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
 NULL | NULL    | NULL
```

My hive-metastore is also stable and working fine. But I an not able to understand why I am getting data as NULL. However, when I query data for `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test`, I get result like 25; rows. This means the table has data in it. How should I resolve this issue?

I am very new to presto. Need help!

Comment: What version of Presto are you running? What file format are you using for your tables? How did you create the tables and insert the data?

Comment: @MartinTraverso I am using presto 0.330. Parquet is the format I have my data in the s3 buckets. I created the table on hive metastore that presto uses. Data is available in the S3 buckets.

Comment: @MartinTraverso I am using CTAS statement as follows - 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table_3 
  ( time TIMESTAMP, 
    quality VARCHAR, 
    pm10 REAL) WITH (format = 'parquet', external_location = 's3a://air-detection/pm10/');

Comment: Ever figure this one out? I'm running into something similar now (with some "struct" fields of a "stored as orc" Hive table), so I'm curious. :-)